# Property does not exist on type when using Material-ui-next

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

When trying to render a TextField from [material-ui-next](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/) website using React 16.3 and TypeScript I'm getting the following error:

```
Property 'label' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TextField> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>
```

My component's tests are passing but it does not build.

```
<TextField
      id="name"
      label="Name"
      className={classes.textField}
      value={this.state.name}
      onChange={this.handleChange('name')}
      margin="normal"
    />
```

**EDIT: 5.04.2018**

I found the cause of this error. I had a package **@types/material-ui** installed which for some reason had a higher priority by TypeScript than type definitions inside the actual material-ui package. 
I removed it and everything works just fine.

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: @KyleRichardson I'm using 2.8.1 version of the TypeScript

Comment: Looks like it has to do with how tsc types JSX elements. This may help you: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15449

Comment: I managed to fix that. I edited my post.